# Product of two iid random variables not iid

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, time-series

Let $\{X_{t}\}$ be a sequence of mean zero independent and identically distributed (iid) random variables. Now define the sequence $\{Y_{t}\}$ as $Y_{t} = X_{t}X_{t-1}$. Show that $Y_{t}$ is not necessarily an iid sequence.

Further Context:

My professor has suggested that this sequence is a white noise process, but is not always an iid process. I have been trying to prove that $Y_{t}$ and $Y_{t+1}$ are not independent but am having difficulty doing this. In particular, I do not know how to show that $\{Y_{t}\}$ is not a sequence of independent variables. I have not been able to find anything online or in my textbooks that deals with this particular problem.

Comment: The exercise is wrong as stated: if $(X_t)$ is i.i.d. Bernoulli with $P(X_t=-1)=P(X_t=+1)=\frac12$ then $(Y_t)$ is independent (actually, $(Y_t)$ is distributed as $(X_t)$).

Comment: This is a good point. I have edited the post to correct. My professor used this example often, and made it seem like it is a common example although I cannot find any mention of it anywhere.

Comment: Since "NOT an i.i.d. sequence" has been replaced by "not necessarily an i.i.d. sequence", now the task is easy. Hint: Try $X_t$ taking the values $1$ and $2$.

Comment: @Did I see your point. This has been helpful, thank you.

Comment: If you reached a full answer to your question, you might want to write it down and to post it as an answer here. After a while, you might even *accept* it. The procedure I suggest is actually *recommended*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to find only one example such that $Y_{t}$ is not an iid sequence.

Suppose $X_{t}\sim Bernoulli(p)$ where $P(X_{t}=1)=P(X_{t}=2)=\frac{1}{2}$. To show $Y_{t}$ is not an iid sequence it suffices to show that $P(Y_{t+1} = a | Y_{t} = b)\neq P(Y_{t+1}=a)$.

Indeed, $a$ and $b$ can take on values $4$, $2$ and $1$ where $Y_{t}$ takes on these values with probability $p^{2}$, $2p^{2}$ and $p^{2}$ respectively. It is easy to see that knowledge of the value of $Y_{t}=b$ will affect the probability of observing $Y_{t+1}=a$.

For example, if $Y_{t} =1$ then $P(Y_{t+1} = 4 | Y_{t} = 1)= 0 \neq P(Y_{t+1}=4)= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}$.

Therefore $P(Y_{t+1} = a | Y_{t} = b)\neq P(Y_{t+1}=a)$ and thus $Y_{t}$ is not an iid sequence.

Comment: The $Y_t$'s might fail to be independent (as you showed) but are for sure identically distributed.